# Wifi adapter rtl8821ce not working on 20.04

Tags: drivers, 19.10, 20.04

I upgraded my hp laptop from 19.10 to 20.04. (new installation).

Now I cannot activate the rtl8821ce WiFi module.

For 19.10. there was a hint in ask ubuntu

```
sudo dpkg -i rtl8821ce-dkms_5.2.5.2.1.30816.20190425-0ubuntu1_all.deb
```

which worked well, but it doesn't work with 20.04.

Comment: What you mean by "doesn't work"? Did the package install with no errors?

Comment: Sorry, I just double-checked. Looks like I am too stupid to type the name of the sub directory properly......

Comment: Everything works fine. The instructions for 18.04 work for 20.04. too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like described in a former post: 
Wifi adapter not found, rtl8821ce no longer working [18.04]